# TCP/IP Printers on a 2012 Domain

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-printer

I have rolled out a 2012 Domain controller and have added my users to it. I use to be able to click "Add Printer" and a list of IP enabled printers would show up, but since everyone is now on the domain controller, when I click "Add Printer" no printers are listed. Can anyone tell me how to either add the printers (maybe through GPO) so that they show up again?

Comment: I went to the GPO and enabled printer browsing and a few other printer options in a GPO. but nothing has worked.

Comment: Do you want the server to act as a print server and handle drivers and print services for the domain/ users?

Comment: Just trying to have TCP/IP printers available to domain users through the "Add Printer" function. This was how we added printers before the Domain.

Comment: More info on size and configuration of the domain would help.  If small and only one server perhaps adding the printers on the server to make browsing/finding easier as the printers would be presented in Active Directory.  Also means only one place to install and manage drivers if you have a mixed user base.

Comment: Have you installed the printers on the Domain Controller and added them to Active Directory?

Answer (score 3):

Install the printers on the Server 2012 box.  Share printers.  Add any needed drivers for your various clients.